# Why does a formatted string with no keys return itself?

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

Considering this Ruby code:

```
format_string = "%{greeting}, %{name}"

puts format_string %{greeting: "Hi", name: "John"}  # <-- returns "Hi, John"
puts format_string                                  # <-- returns "%{greeting}, %{name}" 
puts format_string %{greeting: "Hi"}        # <-- returns key{name} not found (KeyError)"
```

The following code produces an **error because it is missing a key.**

```
puts format_string %{greeting: "Hi"}    # returns "key{name} not found (KeyError)"
```

While the code below returns the exact value of the format_string variable, **even though it missing both keys.** I would expect the value to be equal to nil, or result in an error like the code above.

```
puts format_string      # returns "%{greeting: "Hi", name: "John"}"
```

**I'm looking for an explanation of how and why the exact value is returned, when no keys or variables are set to the string.**
I have read through the ruby docs and multiple web pages relating to ruby formatting, yet I have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your:

```
puts format_string
```

prints `format_string` because that's what `puts` does. The formatting (and complaining about missing keys) that you're seeing is done by the [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) method; `puts` doesn't interpret the `%{...}` things in the string, the `%` operator does that. Perhaps breaking it into two steps (and being more consistent with your whitespace) will clarify things for you:

```
formatted_string = format_string % {greeting: "Hi", name: "John"}
# -------------------------------^ Just an operator like any other, %{ has no special meaning outside the string you use the % operator on.
puts formatted_string
```

The `%` in `format_string % hash` is just an operator like any other, `%{` has no special meaning outside the string you use the `%` operator on so removing the space between the operator (`%`) and the opening brace (`{`) of the hash operand is misleading.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#sprintf) recommends using `sprintf` and `format` instead of `%` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -1):

It's bad design by Ruby.  We should be able to implement partial substitution, one key at a time, without KeyErrors.  This all-or-nothing rule is not well thought through.